# Reactjs: Nothing Was Returned From Render

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I have setup a basic react app using `create-react-app` and created my first component. However, the project is not able to build or render due to this error in browser window:

```
CountDown(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.
./src/index.js
D:/ReactDev/CountDownReact/countdown/src/index.js:8
```

Here's my `index.js` file code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import Bulma from 'bulma/css/bulma.css'
import App from './components/App/App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

and the `App.js` where I have imported the new component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import CountDown from '../countdown/Countdown';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <div className="App">
                Hello React
                <CountDown/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Finally, my `Countdown` component code:

```
import React from 'react';

const CountDown = (props) => {
    <section class="section">
        <div className="hero-body">
            <div class="container">
                <h1 class="title">Section</h1>
                <h2 class="subtitle">
                 A simple container to divide your page into <strong>sections</strong>, like the one you're currently
                reading
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
};
export default CountDown;
```

Do I need to also import my new component here? How do I solve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741247/nothing-was-returned-from-render-this-usually-means-a-return-statement-is-missi)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Countdown component doesn't return anything, you can replace the `{}` with `()` in order to have it return.

```
import React from 'react';

const CountDown = (props) => (
    <section class="section">
        <div className="hero-body">
            <div class="container">
                <h1 class="title">Section</h1>
                <h2 class="subtitle">
                 A simple container to divide your page into <strong>sections</strong>, like the one you're currently
                reading
                </h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
);
export default CountDown;
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 2):

CountDown component doesn't return the JSX. You can add an explicit return statement for returning the JSX.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with this:

> ```
> function Input(props) {
> return 
> <input type={props.type} placeholder={props.placeholder} />
>  }
> ```

Instead it had to be:

> ```
> function Input(props) {
> return <input type={props.type} placeholder={props.placeholder} />
>  }
> ```