# Components, ReactJS - Nothing was returned from render

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, render

I am trying to create a component and calling it in App.jsx (another component) and call this App.jsx in render, but it gives me error this .

**Error:**
Error: App(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

Here is the code which i done .

**Component:**  (Greetings.Jsx)

```
import React from 'react'
function Greetings()
{
    let timehours=new Date()
    timehours=timehours.getHours();
    let cssStyle={
        color:'Green',
        
      }
      
      let text="";
      if(timehours>=1&&timehours<=12)
      {
       
        // z.src = window.location.origin + '/images/morning.jpeg'; 
        // document.body.backgroundImage= z.src;
        text="Good Morning";
        cssStyle.color='Green';
        // bgimg.Image=window.location.origin + '/images/morning.jpg';
        
        
      }
      else if(timehours>=12&&timehours<19)
      {
        
        // bgimg.Image=window.location.origin + '/images/morning.jpg';
        text="Good Afternoon";
        cssStyle.color='Orange';
      }
      else
      {
        text="Good Night";
        cssStyle.color='Black';
      }

      return(
        <>
            <div>
                <h1>   Hello Sir, <span style={cssStyle}>{text}</span></h1>
            </div>  
        </>
      );
}
export default Greetings;
```

**App.Jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import Greetings from './Greetings'

function App()
{
    return 
    (
        <>
            <Greetings/>
        </>
        );
}

export default App;
```

Index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import reactDom from 'react-dom';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";


ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById("root"),);
```

Comment: why do you have `<>` ?

Comment: in `App.Jsx` the paranthese after the return must be on the same line. that is caused by javascript optional semicolon.

Comment: yea, i just recreate the app.jsx, i posted the answer below, and it works now, thank you :)

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741247/nothing-was-returned-from-render-this-usually-means-a-return-statement-is-missi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just recreate the App.jsx file which is

```
import React from 'react'

import Greetings from './Greetings'

function App()
{
    return(<Greetings></Greetings>);
}

export default App;
```

and works for me now!!!

Comment: you can write return(<Greetings/>) too.

Comment: Or `return <Greetings />;`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to have empty brackets and in `App.Jsx` the parantheses after the `return` must be on the same line (special thanks to [@Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1280867/martin)):

Greeting.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'

function Greetings()
{
    // the other code is omitted for the brevity    
    return(            
        <div>
            <h1>   Hello Sir, <span style={cssStyle}>{text}</span></h1>
        </div> 
    );
}
export default Greetings;
```

and:

```
import React from 'react';
import Greetings from './Greetings'

function App()
{
    return <Greetings/>;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Note the `.jsx` extension, which causes this: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-sea-kfln9?file=/src/App.jsx Also see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66984973/components-reactjs-nothing-was-returned-from-render/66985051?noredirect=1#comment118404572_66984973) by Martin

Comment: @ChrisG I see what you mean! Thank you for example!  I've updated answer. I think now there is no reason to downvote:)

Comment: Yeah, I removed my downvote :) Still, your answer doesn't explain what causes the issue; instead it suggests it is caused by the (unnecessary) `<>...</>` wrapper. The error is explicitly the `return` in a line on its own, and any answer to this question should address that. SO is primarily about future users finding this and less about helping the OP. edit: and of course, it's also a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741247/nothing-was-returned-from-render-this-usually-means-a-return-statement-is-missi