# Why I am getting the error: Uncaught Error: HomePage(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Node version: 17.3.0

NPM version: 8.3.0

I am learning react js. While practicing a project I am getting this error.
Error:

```
Uncaught Error: HomePage(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.
```

My code are given below:

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
reportWebVitals();
```

**app.js**

```
import './App.css';
import HomePage from './homepage';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <HomePage />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**homepage.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

const HomePage = () => {
  <div className="homepage">
    <div className="directory-menu">
      <div className="menu-item">
        <div className="content">
          <h1 className="title">HATS</h1>
          <span className="subtitle">SHOP NOW</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>;
};

export default HomePage;
```

**Full image of error**

[image]

How to solve this error? Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Well, the error is telling you exactly what the problem is: your `HomePage` function does not return anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741247/nothing-was-returned-from-render-this-usually-means-a-return-statement-is-missi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning anything from the function.

```
const HomePage = () => {
  return <div className="homepage">
    <div className="directory-menu">
      <div className="menu-item">
        <div className="content">
          <h1 className="title">HATS</h1>
          <span className="subtitle">SHOP NOW</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>;
};
```

or

```
const HomePage = () => (
  <div className="homepage">
    <div className="directory-menu">
      <div className="menu-item">
        <div className="content">
          <h1 className="title">HATS</h1>
          <span className="subtitle">SHOP NOW</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>;
);
```

would be correct way